# 'name' property in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, database-design, doctrine-orm, php-5.3

Say I have a system with Products that can have various decoration (or printing) options.

Most products will have a similar range of printing options names, but some maybe unique for a single product.

For example, I could have a cap that could have three different decoration options:

1. Unbranded
2. One Color Print
3. Embroidery

My goal is trying to minimize decoration option names created by admin users so they are always the same. I.E. I don't want some decoration options being called "1 Color Print" and then another one called "One Color Print".

So my plan is in the UI is to have a drop down of existing decoration options names but also give them the option to add a new one (for the edge cases).

However, each decoration option has various other data with it, like setup cost, production time, etc which varies depending on the product.

For example, Hat1 and Hat2 could both have an embroidery decoration option, but Hat1's setup cost is $49 and Hat2's setup cost is only $35.

So my questions is, what is the best way to structure my entities? Should I have three entities: Product, DecorationOption and DecorationOptionName? Or just two entities: Product and DecorationOption?

Please see my code examples for further understand:

1. [Three entities option](http://pastie.org/1262992)
2. [Two entities option](http://pastie.org/1262996)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the three entity approach, with some minor differences in semantics: Product, Decoration, and ProductDecoration. It's essentially the idea behind a many-to-many join table, but you treat the join as it's own object, where you can store extra information.

Products and Decoration are their own separate entities, and information about the relationship between any given Product and any given DecorationOption is managed in ProductDecoration. You can achieve this using two OneToMany relationships.

```
<?php

class Product 
{   
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductDecoration", mappedBy="product") */
    private $productDecorations;

}


class Decoration
{   
   /** @Column(type="string") */
   private $name;   

   /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductDecoration", mappedBy="decoration") */
   private $productDecorations;
}

class ProductDecorations
{   

   /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="productDecorations") */
   private $product;

   /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Decoration", inversedBy="productDecorations") */
   private $decoration;

   /** @Column(type="integer") */
   private $setupCost;

   /** @Column(type="integer") */
   private $productionTime
}
```

The only way I'd recommend using the two Entity approach is if you can anticipate never needing more than the 'name' column for the Decoration entity, and you're not bothered by potential database normalization issues.

Comment: Perfect! Do you think this would be necessary if there wasn't extra info on the joining table? For example, a product has several images all of which will be labelled (Front, Back, Top, etc) but there are some products that will have edge-case labels, but I want to keep naming as consistent as possible. Take a look here: http://pastie.org/1268445

Comment: Well I guess ImagePosition isn't the joining table... but you get the idea/question I hope.

Comment: It's hard to say for every example. Basically, if you need an object to perform business logic on, you should probably have an entity for it. If you have a complex set of logic supporting that label system, make an entity. If not you're probably okay with the two tables. Also, Doctrine does have a @ManyToMany association that uses a join table without the need to create a third entity.